# Scrapy: Images Pipeline, download images

Tags: python, scrapy, scraper

Following: [scrapy's](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html) tutorial i made a simple image crawler (scrapes images of Bugattis). Which is illustrated below in **EXAMPLE**.

However, following the guide has left me with a non functioning crawler! It finds all of the urls but it does not download the images.

I found a duck tape solution: replace `ITEM_PIPELINES` and `IMAGES_STORE` such that;

`ITEM_PIPELINES['scrapy.pipeline.images.FilesPipeline'] = 1` and

`IMAGES_STORE` -> `FILES_STORE`

But I do not know why this works? I would like to use the ImagePipeline as documented by scrapy.

**EXAMPLE**

**settings.py**

```
BOT_NAME = 'imagespider'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['imagespider.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'imagespider.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'scrapy.pipelines.images.ImagesPipeline': 1,
}
IMAGES_STORE = "/home/user/Desktop/imagespider/output"
```

**items.py**

```
import scrapy

class ImageItem(scrapy.Item):
    file_urls = scrapy.Field()
    files = scrapy.Field()
```

**imagespider.py**

```
from imagespider.items import ImageItem
import scrapy


class ImageSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "imagespider"

    start_urls = (
        "https://www.find.com/search=bugatti+veyron",
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        for elem in response.xpath("//img"):
            img_url = elem.xpath("@src").extract_first()
            yield ImageItem(file_urls=[img_url])
```

Comment: Could you please post the `__main__` stub?  How do we enter these functions?

Comment: **___main___** would be standard Scrapy code, a boilerplate. It would invoke a spider which is this code. The code, I agree with you is incomplete, however one could speculate what other moving parts would look like.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The item your spider returns must contains fields `"file_urls"` for files and/or `"image_urls"` for images. In your code you specify settings for Image pipeline but your return urls in `"file_urls"`.

Simply change this line:

```
yield ImageItem(file_urls=[img_url])
# to
yield {'image_urls': [img_url]}
```

* scrapy can return dictionary objects instead of items, which saves time when you only have one or two fields.

Comment: Thanks! You could also change `ImageItem` to have `image_urls` and `yield ImageItem(image_urls=[img_url])`

Answer (score 7):

Spent hours investigating why built-int ImagePipeline doesn't work on my local.
Finally, I found this from documentation

```
The Images Pipeline requires Pillow 4.0.0 or greater. It is used for thumbnailing and normalizing images to JPEG/RGB format.
```

After installed Pillow. it works normally.

Comment: Wow, I wish this was more visible in the scraping output - the silent failure is surprising. Docs are [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#using-the-images-pipeline). Thanks for sharing!